# Can this be done in MySQL? a combined insert and lookup query

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

Have tables Users and Items
Users: Username (varchar, no duplicates), Password (varchar), User_id(unique auto increment INT) Items: Item_name(varchar), Item_id (unique auto increment INT), Owner_id (must be from Users user_id)

So you are given an Item_name and a Username. You want to create a new item in Items with that information. So on one hand you first need to find out the User_id given a username, and then insert an item into Items table making the Owner_id field = User_id that you found.

Sorry, I'm very confused by how to do his in a single statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
insert into item (item_name, owner_id) values (
    ?, (select u.user_id from user u where u.username = ?)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into item (item_name, owner_id) 
select 'new_name', u.user_id 
from user u 
where u.username = 'old_name'
```